# Why does std::vec::Vec implement two kinds of the Extend trait?

Tags: rust, lifetime

The struct `std::vec::Vec` implements two kinds of Extend, as specified [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Extend%3C%26%27a%20T%3E) – `impl<'a, T> Extend<&'a T> for Vec<T>` and `impl<T> Extend<T> for Vec<T>`.  The documentation states that the first kind is an "Extend implementation that copies elements out of references before pushing them onto the Vec".  I'm rather new to Rust, and I'm not sure if I'm understanding it correctly.

I would guess that the first kind is used with the equivalent of C++ normal iterators, and the second kind is used with the equivalent of C++ move iterators.

I'm trying to write a function that accepts any data structure that will allow inserting `i32`s to the back, so I take a parameter that implements both kinds of `Extend`, but I can't figure out how to specify the generic parameters to get it to work:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = std::vec::Vec::<i32>::new();
    add_stuff(&mut vec);
}

fn add_stuff<'a, Rec: std::iter::Extend<i32> + std::iter::Extend<&'a i32>>(receiver: &mut Rec) {
    let x = 1 + 4;
    receiver.extend(&[x]);
}
```

The compiler complains that `&[x]` "creates a temporary which is freed while still in use" which makes sense because `'a` comes from outside the function `add_stuff`.  But of course what I want is for `receiver.extend(&[x])` to copy the element out of the temporary array slice and add it to the end of the container, so the temporary array will no longer be used after `receiver.extend` returns.  What is the proper way to express what I want?

Answer (score 2):

From the outside of `add_stuff`, `Rect` must be able to be extended with a reference whose lifetime is given in the inside of `add_stuff`. Thus, you could require that `Rec` must be able to be extended with references of any lifetime using higher-ranked trait bounds:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = std::vec::Vec::<i32>::new();
    add_stuff(&mut vec);
}

fn add_stuff<Rec>(receiver: &mut Rec)
    where
        for<'a> Rec: std::iter::Extend<&'a i32>
{
    let x = 1 + 4;
    receiver.extend(&[x]);
}
```

Moreover, as you see, the trait bounds were overly tight. One of them should be enough if you use `receiver` consistently within `add_stuff`.

That said, I would simply require `Extend<i32>` and make sure that `add_stuff` does the right thing internally (if possible):

```
fn add_stuff<Rec>(receiver: &mut Rec)
    where
        Rec: std::iter::Extend<i32>
{
    let x = 1 + 4;
    receiver.extend(std::iter::once(x));
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I would simply require Extend<i32> and make sure that add_stuff does the right thing internally (if possible)"?  I tried doing `fn add_stuff<Rec: std::iter::Extend<i32>>(receiver: &mut Rec) { let x = 1 + 4; receiver.extend(&[x]); }`, which doesn't work either.  The compiler complains `expected reference, found i32`.